# Find index of javascript sparse array closest to given index

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have a sparse array with the value "foo" assigned to index 100, and the value "bar" assigned to index 130. How can I "round" any given index such that it always returns the value of the nearest defined index?

For example: if I attempt to get the value at index 103, I should get "foo" instead of undefined. Similarly, a too-low index of 99 should still give me "foo", and 115 should round up to "bar" at index 130.

This should be totally independent of (and unrelated to) the values stored at the indices.

**EDIT:** Solved in <s>O(log(n)) time</s> O(n) time using a condensed array and a bracketing search. Note that this requires the condensed array to be sorted low to high.

```
var sparseArr = [];
sparseArr[100] = "foo";
sparseArr[130] = "bar";
sparseArr[150] = "foobar";

var condensedArr = [100, 130, 150];

function roundGet(index) {
  var mid;
  var lo = 0;
  var hi = condensedArr.length - 1;
  while (hi - lo > 1) {
    mid = Math.floor((lo + hi) / 2);
    if (condensedArr[mid] < index) {
      lo = mid;
    } else {
      hi = mid;
    }
  }
  if (index - condensedArr[lo] <= condensedArr[hi] - index) {
    return sparseArr[condensedArr[lo]];
  }
  return sparseArr[condensedArr[hi]];
}
```

Example at https://jsfiddle.net/xfevha56/

Comment: You should at least show us what you have so far, SO is not a code writing service

Comment: How would you expect to retrieve these values? The native array indexer would always return undefined for an index without a value...

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith So far I have created a separate non-sparse array which lists all occupied indices (in this example, [100, 130]) and used a simple algorithm to loop over this second array and find the closest number to my index. However, it is growing inefficient very quickly (n^2 time) so I'd like to find a better answer.

Comment: @BrendanWalsh so post the code you currently have in your question, make a working example in a fiddle if possible.

Comment: Consider using an object proxy.

Comment: Are there only two defined values?

Comment: Your algorithm will only work correctly if `condensedArr` is sorted. And you should count the operations of creating this array as part of algorithm complexity, it will take O(n) operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), which iterates only the non-sparsed items.

```js
function roundGet(index) {
    var last = -Infinity,
        value;
    a.some(function (v, i) {
        if (Math.abs(last - index) <= Math.abs(i - index)) {
            return true;
        }
        value = v;
        last = i;
    });
    return value;
}

var a = [];
a[100] = 'foo';
a[130] = 'bar';
a[150] = 'foobar';

console.log(roundGet(0));    // "foo"
console.log(roundGet(99));   // "foo"
console.log(roundGet(103));  // "foo"
console.log(roundGet(115));  // "foo"
console.log(roundGet(116));  // "bar"
console.log(roundGet(186));  // "foobar"
console.log(roundGet(1000)); // "foobar"
```

ES6

```js
function roundGet(index) {
    var last = -Infinity,
        value;
    a.some((v, i) =>
        Math.abs(last - index) <= Math.abs(i - index) || (value = v, last = i, false));
    return value;
}

var a = [];
a[100] = 'foo';
a[130] = 'bar';
a[150] = 'foobar';

console.log(roundGet(0));    // "foo"
console.log(roundGet(99));   // "foo"
console.log(roundGet(103));  // "foo"
console.log(roundGet(115));  // "foo"
console.log(roundGet(116));  // "bar"
console.log(roundGet(186));  // "foobar"
console.log(roundGet(1000)); // "foobar"
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said anything about browser support, so here is solution using some array manipulation functions (IE9+) and ES2015 function arrow syntax.

```
function findIndex(array, searchedIndex) {
  return Object.keys(array)
               .map(e => ({val: parseInt(e, 10), abs: Math.abs(parseInt(e, 10) - searchedIndex)}))
               .reduce((min, e) => min[0].val > e.abs ? [{val: e.abs, i: e.val}] : min, [{val: Number.MAX_VALUE, i: -1}])
               .reduce((v, min) => min.val !== Number.MAX_VALUE ?  array[min.i] : v, -1)
}
```

You can try it on [Babel online REPL](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=function%20findIndex(array%2C%20searchedIndex)%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20Object.keys(array)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.map(e%20%3D%3E%20(%7Bval%3A%20parseInt(e%2C%2010)%2C%20abs%3A%20Math.abs(parseInt(e%2C%2010)%20-%20searchedIndex)%7D))%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.reduce((min%2C%20e)%20%3D%3E%20min%5B0%5D.val%20%3E%20e.abs%20%3F%20%5B%7Bval%3A%20e.abs%2C%20i%3A%20e.val%7D%5D%20%3A%20min%2C%20%5B%7Bval%3A%20Number.MAX_VALUE%2C%20i%3A%20-1%7D%5D)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.reduce((v%2C%20min)%20%3D%3E%20min.val%20!%3D%3D%20Number.MAX_VALUE%20%3F%20%20array%5Bmin.i%5D%20%3A%20v%2C%20-1)%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20searchedIndex%20%3D%20155%0Avar%20array%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0Aarray%5B99%5D%20%3D%20'foo'%0Aarray%5B129%5D%20%3D%20'bar'%0A%0A_.range(90%2C%20150).forEach(searchedIndex%20%3D%3E%20console.log(searchedIndex%2C%20'%3D'%2C%20findIndex(array%2C%20searchedIndex)))).

Answer (score 0):

You might do it as follows;

```js
function findCloseIndex(a,idx){
  return Object.keys(a)
               .map(k => [k,Math.abs(k-idx)])
               .sort((a,b) => a[1] - b[1])[0][0];
}

var arr = [],
  close;

arr[100] = "foo";
arr[130] = "bar";

close = arr[findCloseIndex(arr,125)];
console.log(close);
close = arr[findCloseIndex(arr,78)];
console.log(close);
```